# Signature implementation in FSharp

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Implement a signature in Fsharp

The Signature: MyLibrary.fsi

```
namespace myLib
module public MyModule1 =
    val addition : p:float -> float
```

The Implementation: MyLibrary.fs

```
namespace myLib
module public MyModule1 = 
    let addition p = p*2.0
```

The Testing

```
#load "C:\@@@@@\Projects\MyLibrary.fsi"
#load "C:\@@@@@\Projects\MyLibrary.fs"
open myLib.MyModule1
```

The error:

> C:\@@@@@\Projects\MyLibrary.fsi(1,1): error FS0240: The signature file 'FSI_0015_MyLibrary' does not have a corresponding implementation file. If an implementation file exists then check the 'module' and 'namespace' declarations in the signature and implementation files match.

@@@@@ is the equivalent of my full path

Comment: You don't `#load` a signature file.

Comment: How do I then create the "bridge" between my signature and implementation? In Java I would write:
 MyModule implements iMyModule

Comment: You compile them into a `.dll`.  Also, I think you actually want a class - you do `type t() = inherit something()` which is like java interface

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I have understood what you are after. Please let me know if you need sth else?

```
module public MyModule =
        type IMyModule1 = 
            abstract member addition : double -> double
        type MyModule =
            interface IMyModule1 with 
                member this.addition p = p*2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are running 2 different load statements. Each load has to be able to complete as a valid statement. If you combine the two statements it should work. You also need to escape the slashes. I did that using the '@' prefix. Here is an example:

```
#load @"C:\@@@@@\Projects\MyLibrary.fsi" @"C:\@@@@@\Projects\MyLibrary.fs"
open myLib.MyModule1
```